# How to handle number overflow?

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting, integer-overflow

I am calculating a trend line slope using numpy:

```
xs = []
ys = []
my_x = 0
for i in range(2000):
    my_x += 1
    ys.append(5*my_x+random.rand())
    xs.append(my_x)

A = matrix(xs).T;
b = matrix(ys).T;
N = A.T*A
U = A.T*b
print N,U
a = (N.I*U)[0,0]    
print a
```

The result I get is `a=-8.2053307679` instead of the expected `5`. Probably it happends beacuse the number in variable `N` is too big.

How to overcome this problem ? any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

When I run the code, the answer is as you would expect:

```
[[2668667000]] [[  1.33443472e+10]]
5.00037927592
```

It's probably due to the fact that you're on a 32-bit system, and I'm on a 64-bit system. Instead, you can use

```
A = matrix(xs, dtype='float64').T;
b = matrix(ys, dtype='float64').T;
```

Just FYI, when using numpy you'll be much more efficient if you work on vectorizing your algorithms. For example, you could replace the first several lines with this:

```
xs = np.arange(2000)
ys = 5 * xs + np.random.rand(2000)
```

---

Edit – one more thing: numerically, it is a bad idea to explicitly invert matrices when doing computations like these. It would be better to use something like `a = np.linalg.solve(N, U)[0, 0]` in your algorithm. It won't make a big difference here, but if you move to more complicated problems it definitely will! For some discussion this, take a look at [this article](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/19/dont-invert-that-matrix/).

Answer (score 0):

:) The problem solved by using:

```
A = matrix(xs,float64).T;
b = matrix(ys,float64).T;
```